Time atoms remain in delimited regions
I am trying to verify the time atoms remain in each region (z boundaries for each region). One strategy I thought of is, at each simulation step, to cumulatively count the number of times the atom is found at position z within each region. In general, I need to account for the residence time of each atom in the salt group. For this, I extract the ID keys, atomic type, and z-coordinate of each atom using the compute method, define the regions in the variables in_region1, in_region2, and in_region3, but I can't find documentation for any method that accumulates values from simulation parameter readings. Obviously, ave/atom doesn't work for this, but I included it as an illustrative example. Any suggestions on what to use, or alternative thoughts instead of trying to use a known intrinsic method in LAMMPS?
I made some additions to compare the z-coordinates with the regions, but I also removed them from the code because they didn't work.
Parte of the code:
# Dump
# ===================================================
dump           1 all xyz 10 traj_nvt.xyz
dump_modify    1 element C F He N H O Na Cl

# Variables to accumulate the residence time in each region
variable count_region1 atom 0
variable count_region2 atom 0
variable count_region3 atom 0

# Fix to check the presence of atoms in the regions
compute salt_positions salt property/atom id type z

# Fixes that store whether the atom is in each region
variable in_region1 atom "z > 0.28 && z <= 33.80024"
variable in_region2 atom "z > 33.80024 && z <= 67.3248"
variable in_region3 atom "z > 67.3248 && z <= 100.8472"

# Summing the residence time
fix count1 salt ave/atom 1 1 1 v_in_region1
fix count2 salt ave/atom 1 1 1 v_in_region2
fix count3 salt ave/atom 1 1 1 v_in_region3

# Save the results to a file
# Use the IDs of the fixes to access the accumulated time data
dump dump_counts salt custom 100 permanence_times.txt id type f_count1 f_count2 f_count3

# Simulation loop
run 100

